# Pipeline pass parameters to downstream jobs from upstream job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I created two jenkins pipeline jobs and both are dependency jobs. Here I want to pass parameters value from one job to another. I am new to pipeline job creation. Please give reply for this question with examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipeline step: [build](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#-build-%20build%20a%20job)

```
// NEXT_JOB is the job path of the next job.

build (job: "${NEXT_JOB}", parameters: [
        [
            $class: 'StringParameterValue',
            name: 'DOWN_PARAM_1',
            value: "${env.UP_PARAM_1}"
        ],
        [
            $class: 'StringParameterValue',
            name: 'DOWN_PARAM_2',
            value: "${env.UP_PARAM_2}"
        ]
    ],
    wait: true)
```

Comment: I have one more doubt . is it possible to pass one env variable from one jenkins file to another jenkins file.

Comment: I can't get your exact meaning.  If your next job is a pipeline job and pipeline script from SCM, it must be upon on a Jenkinsfile.  You can pass down any value (like `parameter / build environment variable/ groovy variable created in runtime of previous job`) as job parameter for the next job as code in my answer using `build` to invoke the next job with specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below method too

```
stages {
    stage('job') {
        steps {
            echo "${params}"
            script {
                def myparams = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction).getParameters()
                build job: 'downstream-pipeline-with-params', parameters: myparams
            }
        }
    }
}
```